# launching ios simulator with expo, receiving 'Unable to resolve module'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please see image below to assist. I can't seem to work out where i'm going wrong?

This is my first time using expo so I am fairly confused with it. I'm trying to launch my react app on the ios simulator but receiving the error message;

```
iOS Bundling failed 18ms
Unable to resolve module ./App from /Users/luke/Desktop/Projects/simulate/index.js:

None of these files exist:
  * App(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  * App/index(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)
  1 | import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';
  2 |
> 3 | import App from './App';
```

```js
INDEX.JS


import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './Components/App/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
```

```js
APP.JS

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: can we take a look at the code?

Comment: which section of code would you like to see?

Comment: index and app, btw is this your first time using expo?

Comment: Yes, this is my first time using expo, can you tell? haha It is fairly confusing. I have added the code for App.js and index.js

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because you deleted your App.js from your tree, so your project is trying to get access to a file that doesn´t exist

You must have something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJC4j.png)

Comment: interesting as when I created the React app it never had that. does app.tsx add itself when creating react-app?

Comment: Yes React create it automatically, in case that expo delete it You can create again, i work with typescript thats why i have a App.tsx